# How to write sql for this situation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very confused with how to make the sql statement for this scenario. I have been trying but no luck so hopefully one can help. I have 3 tables: table PARENTS, table CHILDREN, and table SCHOOL

```
-PARENTS has
ID      name


-Children has
ID    parentID   nam

-SCHOOL has 

ID   parentID   chidrenID   schoolType
```

What I want is to return all parents with their children (whether they are enrolled in school or not) but if they are enrolled in school then  I need the schoolType to be "highschool"

So something along these lines (pseaduo code):

```
Select * from parents,children 
where parents.ID = Children.parentID and 
include school information 
where parents.ID = school.parentID and 
children.ID = school.childrenID and schoolType = "HighSchool"
```

Any help???

Comment: As a side note, `SCHOOL.parentID` isn't needed - the information can (and potentially should) be derived from `CHILDREN.parentID`.  Other than that.... look into boolean conditions - you're going to need an `OR` (parenthesis around the `AND` conditions will make the logic more obvious).  And please, learn to explicitly qualify your joins, the implicit syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) just makes some future queries harder.

Comment: What have you tried so far in SQL that would implement your pseudo-code? This looks like a pretty simple set of `JOIN` operations and a `WHERE` condition on `schoolType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need some like this:

```
SELECT * from PARENTS P
         inner join CHILDREN C
             on P.ID=C.parentID
         left join SCHOOL S
            on  P.ID=S.parentID
            and C.ID=S.childrenID
WHERE S.schoolType is null
   OR S.schoolType = 'HighSchool'
```

Comment: I don't want to use the null as a value as I could simply not have rows in school as at all and I still want to display children and parents. Plus I am havig issues "near inner". I am using sql lite

Comment: Nerver mind , it worked. I had a stupid spelling mistake. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM PARENTS p
INNER JOIN CHILDREN c ON p.ID = c.parentID
LEFT JOIN SCHOOL s ON c.ID = s.childrenID AND 'HighSchool' = s.schoolType
```

Comment: For some reason it is not working. Giving an error near INNER. Does sql lite differ? As I am using sqlite

Comment: Perhaps it is different, not sure as I haven't used sql lite.  Seems you have the answer above :)